# php Mysql issue with a prepared query in joint table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating an app, and I have a joint table between Blog posts and Comments.
So let say I have a page with the list of posts, when I want to see the detail view then I put the Id of that post in parameter in the url which I hydrate my setters with somewhere in my app.
In that detail view of the post I have a form to add comments; however when I try to insert the IDs of both the post and the comment itself, It doesn't work here is my query/method that does that:

```
Public function insertPost(Articles $article)
    {
//here I insert the comment
        $sql = $this->getBdd()->prepare('INSERT INTO comments(comment, date_comment) 
                                                    VALUES (?,NOW())');
        $sql->execute(array($article->getContent()));

//here I try to insert the ID of the comment and the related ID of my post (since I added the class as a dependency in my method I can still get the id)
        $sql2 = $this->getBdd()->prepare('
INSERT INTO joint_a_comments(id_comment,id_article)
SELECT comments.id, articles.id
FROM comments, articles
WHERE comments.id = (SELECT id FROM comments ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1)
                                                    AND articles.id = "'.$article->getId().'" ');
        $sql2->execute();
    }
```

Do you guys see anything wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you tried outputting or capturing the output from $this->getBdd()->errorInfo(); after trying to insert the row..This might give an indication of any problems.

Comment: yes I did @Peter but as Kyoya mentioned the query wasn't the right one for what I was trying to do... So I actually changed my code and just put another insert values instead and now it's fine; Thanks mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you insert your comment we can grab the comment id and article id like so :

```
$sql = $this->getBdd()->prepare('INSERT INTO comments(comment, date_comment) VALUES (?,NOW())');
$sql->execute(array($article->getContent()));

$comment_id = $this->getBdd()->lastInsertId();

$article_id = $article->getId();

$sql2 = $this->getBdd()->prepare('
INSERT INTO joint_a_comments(id_comment,id_article) VALUES(?, ?)');

 $sql2->execute([$comment_id, $article_id]);
```

Comment: yes makes complete sense!! God sometimes I make more difficult than it is... anyway thanks mate! :))

Comment: it's o-k. but If any of the answers has solved your problem Please accept it.

Comment: yep; just did now ;)

Answer (score 0):

If the `id` is an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column, you can use `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` right after the execution of the first `INSERT` statement. `LAST_INSERT_ID()` will return the inserted value of an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column.

Try this one:

```
public function insertPost(Articles $article)
{
    $db = $this->getBdd();
    //here I insert the comment
    $sql = $db->prepare(
        'INSERT INTO comments(comment, date_comment) VALUES (?,NOW())'
    );

    $sql->execute(array($article->getContent()));
    $commentId = $db->query('SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()')->fetchColumn();


    //here I try to insert the ID of the comment and the related ID of my post (since I added the class as a dependency in my method I can still get the id)
    $sql2 = $db->prepare(
        'INSERT INTO joint_a_comments(id_comment,id_article)
            SELECT comments.id, articles.id
            FROM comments, articles
            WHERE
                comments.id = ? AND
                articles.id = ?'
    );

    $sql2->execute([$commentId, $article->getId()]);
}
```

Comment: thanks for that! however It still not workin, I don't get it, I was sure your solution would work though...? I did a var_dump on $commentId when I submitted the request and I got the right id however it doesn't insert it for any reason... I'll check further

Comment: Try the answer from @AmrAly
The `SELECT` in the 2nd `INSERT` makes no sense, because you select the two columns which you use in your `WHERE` clause. But to make another thing clear: With the statement `SELECT comments.id, articles.id FROM comments, articles WHERE comments.id = ? AND articles.id = ?` MySQL don't know how to join both tables, so it will join **all** rows from `comments` with **all** rows from `articles`.

Comment: yep, that's true no sense at all... Anyway it's how you learn right. Thanks @Kyoya

Comment: Learning is a never ending process ;)